# REGEX, find string that contain string in string

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, rules

I have the following text and i need a preg_match_all that finds all of the strings that start with [ and end with ] that contain at least a string with between {}, i tried and failed to build a correct regex for this, anyone can help with this?

```
Go home [if you have {a-home} or not] [or yes, you do have]
```

Comment: "i tried and failed to build a correct regex for this", show us what you've tried.

Comment: How about `\[[^\]]+\]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this will suit your case `\[[^[]*?{.+?}.*?\]`

By your statement I assumed you must have something between the `{ }` to match, but if it isn't the case just change the `+` for `*` .

Try it here [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YwDjrh/3)

Comment: Hello, It's almost right, the problem is that if i have multiple syntaxes like: Go home [if you have {a-home} or not]   [ or {a-home} ]  [ AND {a-home} or not][or yes, you do have] , it must find all of the ones matching that rule, at the moment it finds only 1 that contains them all.

Comment: To achieve that, you might want something like this: `\[.*?{.+?}.*?\]` just a small modification to the OPs to stop the `.*` and `.+` from being greedy

Comment: @Kyle even that won't help with `[h][e{ll}o]`. This should rather be solved using a negated character class.

Comment: @PepeleaRazvanIonut try it now, credits to Kyle and Sebastian.

Comment: This still gives non-correct results for stuff like `[h{][e{ll}o]` where the curly brackets are incorrectly nested. Dunno if that's a concern for the OP.

Comment: @SebastianProske That should be a match under OPs specification though. Guess I'll update the answer again if he has such concern, having fun evolving this thing with you guys ;P

Comment: Thank you very much, in a practical way, i have no problems with it as it does exactly what it should do, e hope i never  have the example mentioned above to break the code, although the string where it searches is entered by the user and errors can appear at any moment.

Comment: Thank you very much, in a practical way, i have no problems with it as it does exactly what it should do, e hope i never  have the example mentioned above to break the code, although the string where it searches is entered by the user and errors can appear at any moment.

Comment: Hello, sorry for resurrecting such an old post, it worked very well for most of the cases but I ran into some situations that it's still not working as it should, here is a case where it also finds/replaces the values inside [] but without {}, here is an example: [buy from T-Shirts] {p} [FairySeason] [by {p}] [price from {p} to {p}] [price at least {p} discounted]